# Linux swap slowing my system?

Tags: linux, memory, performance, swap

Can swap really slow the system because it uses the hard-disk as a RAM unit ?

I have Fedora 24 (Gnome) here with 8 gigabytes of swap and 6 gigabytes of ram , but i am noticing a very bad conditional lag when using the system , when i open the monitor i find that the hard-disk usage is high .

Note : Although i used this laptop on windows and it was noticeably faster than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *worst* case scenarios, sure, it should. That said, swap is usually the *last* place you'd store pages on, if ram was available, and with 6gb, you should *typically* not be experiencing that much swapping.

Typically system slowdowns due to swap would be due to *insufficient ram* + high ram demand (which results in heavy swapping) + slow drives - I've had systems with insufficient ram perform better with even a low end SSD.

As is though there's insufficient information to say if *your* system is having performance issues cause of swapping.

Something like iotop would show you what processes are using the disk and are using ram and swap, rather than guessing blindly

[image]